# Проблема при генерации символов

Tags: c++, char, хеширование

код ниже генерирует случайное слово длины n. Проблема заключается в том, что он генерирует слово длины n, а затем сразу после него добавляет 'ээээ' и получается "hdkshgksээээ". Есть вариант просто стирать последние четыре символа, но хочется решить проблему более адекватно, из-за чего такое может быть? setlocale(0, "") на это не влияет, насколько мне стало ясно.

```
char *word = new char[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        word[i] = ('a' + rand()%('z' - 'a'));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас нет завершающего '\0' нуля в конце массива, поэтому, когда вы выводите word на консоль, символы выводятся до того момента, когда встретится этот '\0' - в том числе и за пределами выделенной вами памяти.

Answer (score 2):

У вас нет '\0' в конце строки - и из-за этого может выводиться все что угодно пока он не найдется

Далее - у вас метка C++ по этому я бы устранил следующие проблемы

1. для генерации псевдослучайных чисел есть random в std там есть к примеру - std::mt19937_64
2. для работы со строками все же есть string и вам не придется управлять руками вставкой терминирующего нуля
3. генерация от a до z это конечно хорошо, но не гибко я бы добавил все же какой-то набор символов для генерации

накидал для вас прмиер кода
По сути тут есть простой генератор чисел в требуемом диапазоне
и набор символов из которого будет производиться выборка для инжекта в Вашу случайную строку

алгоритм прост -

1. говорим размер требуемой строки
2. создаем псевдо случайный генератор
3. начинаем производить выборку по случайному индексу и заполнять строку

код :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <random>

static unsigned int GenRandInt(unsigned int low = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::min(),
                               unsigned int high = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max())
{
    static std::random_device r_dev{};
    static std::mt19937_64 mt_engine(r_dev());

    static unsigned int _low{low};
    static unsigned int _high{high};
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> u_int_d{static_cast<int32_t>(_low), static_cast<int32_t>(_high)};

    if (_low != low && _high != high)
    {
        _low = low;
        _high = high;
        u_int_d = std::uniform_int_distribution<>{static_cast<int32_t>(_low), static_cast<int32_t>(_high)};
    }

    return static_cast<unsigned int>(u_int_d(mt_engine));
}

static decltype(auto) CreateGenCharObj()
{
    static const unsigned char charset[] = " "
                                           ".,?!-_@#$%&*()[]{}:;"
                                           "0123456789"
                                           "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                                           "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    static unsigned int charset_size{sizeof(charset) - 1};

    return [&]() { return charset[GenRandInt(0, charset_size)]; };
}

std::string GenRandString(std::size_t size)
{
    if (!size)
    {
        return {};
    }
    static auto gen_char_obj{CreateGenCharObj()};
    std::string line(size, 0);
    std::generate(std::begin(line), std::end(line), gen_char_obj);

    return line;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i{0}; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << GenRandString(GenRandInt(10, 20)) << "\n" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```